Should the inline keyword be used for variables in anonymous namespaces in a .cpp file?
If I have a constexpr defined in an anonymous namespace in a .cpp file. Should it be declared as inline? Or not?
What would be the difference between the two declarations?
// In my.cpp 
namespace { 
constexpr int kVal{4};
// or
inline constexpr int kOtherVal{4};
} // anonymous namespace

// Later a class or function in my.cpp uses the constant



I do not think there is any reason to.  All names in an unnamed namespace have internal linkage.  inline is not a sign for inline this code for me, although it can be used as a hint the compiler is free to ignore it for inlining purposes.

It doesn't really make a difference.    Names (including of variables) in an unnamed namespace have internal linkage.   inline allows each source file to separately define the variable, without the problems of multiple definitions.    So you're achieving the same thing, with or without the inline keyword.   Also, at most, inline is a hint to the compiler, and the compiler is permitted to ignore it (i.e.  if adding inline could achieve anything more than placing the variable in an anonymous namespace, with your particular compiler, your compiler is not required to do it).

See dupe: Are objects in anonymous namespace implicitly static?

Another dupe: What standard says about anonymous namespace and internal linkage?

Marking an entity as inline can serve 2 purposes:

Hint for the compiler for optimization (but it may ignore it anyway) - for functions.
Declaring multiple definitions between translation units not to be an ODR violation.

But since all names in an unnamed namespace (including variable names) have internal linkage, this is not really relevant in this case (only one translation unit has access to the name).
Therefore it does not really make a difference here.

What would (1) do for variables (as opposed to functions)?

@HolyBlackCat you are right. Changed the phrasing.
